# In Javascript, how can I extract values of a kind and make simple array from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For example, in the below object, I want to extract first three values of the `value` and make a new simple array `{ -0.30771, 1.0031, 0.0001}`. Why is the expression like `ts.slice(0,4).value` impossible ?

```
ts = [
   {time: "1",
    value: -0.30771},
   {time: "2",
    value: 1.0031  },
   {time: "3",
    value: 0.0001  },
    ...
 ]
```

Comment: *"Why is the expression like "ts.slice(0,4).value" impossible ?"* `ts` appears to be an **object** (even if it's syntactically incorrect), not an array. Only arrays have a `slice` method.

Comment: Any chance to see a *real* `ts`? What you already posted makes not much sense

Comment: The object is not a valid object at all

Comment: function pluck(a){return a[this];} arr=ts.map(pluck, "value")

Comment: Its amazing to get the responses so quickly. I am sorry for my mistake to post erroneous example. My array is a little complex like following: [ {name: "m1", values: [{time: "1", value: -0.3641}, {time: "2", value: 0.5031}, ...]}, {name: "m2", values:[{time: "1", value: -0.3641}, {time: "2", value: 0.5031}, ...]},... ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FelixKling noted, this is being intialized as an object, not an array (due to the use of `{}` ). Because objects don't allow duplicate keys, the end result of this assignment operation is going to be:

`ts = {time:"3", value:0.0001}`

So you don't even have 3 'value's to choose from. I would suggest restructuring your data, perhaps to something like this:

```
ts = [
    {time: "1",value: -0.30771},
    {time: "2",value: 1.0031},
    {time: "3",value: 0.0001},
]
```

Then you could use something like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to collect them:

`ts.map(function (v, idx, array) { return v.value; })`

The link to `map` also contains a polyfill, in case you need it.

```js
ts = [
 {time: "1",value: -0.30771},
 {time: "2",value: 1.0031},
 {time: "3",value: 0.0001},
];
  
values = ts.map(function (el, idx, array) { return el.value; });
document.write(values);

// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
    //    value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
    //    method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) 
    //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and 
    //    len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
        //    method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal 
        //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument 
        //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor 
        // { Value: mappedValue, 
        //   Writable: true, 
        //   Enumerable: true, 
        //   Configurable: true },
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, k, { 
        //   value: mappedValue, 
        //   writable: true, 
        //   enumerable: true, 
        //   configurable: true 
        // });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you and dandavis, I now got one code working well. ts.values.slice(0,4).map(function(v) { return v.value})

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Underscore, then just

```
_.pluck(ts, 'value')
```